# Is it possible to disable central locking on a Jaguar S-type (2000)

Tags: electrical, locks

One of the many problems with my car is that occasionally I can't lock it because a mechanical problem in the passenger side front door interferes with the central locking process.

I lock the drivers side door, I hear the mechanism lock around the car,  then the mechanism immediately unlocks.  I punched the passenger side door and got the whole lot to lock.

To avoid the risk of one day having to leave my car unlocked, is there a way I can deliberately disable central locking so that the door locks behave indepentendly of each other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is probably just as easy to fix the problem! There are two ways to disable it - either remove the fuse from the central locking system (if there is one fuse that only powers that), or disconnect the wiring from the driver's door actuator, so that locking that door does not trigger the system.

If you're going to do the latter, you might as well do the passenger door instead...

Remove the passenger door trim - this will involve finding and removing all the screws, of which there will be several, mostly holding on things like the inner handle. Remove the handle and other trim components - this will involve unhooking the rod that works the handle. Once you've done that, prise off the clips that hold the trim on - the easiest way is to slide a blunt, flat object between the trim and the door and use that to pop them out. A workshop manual or a set of photos might help here...

Once you have the trim off, you'll find a plastic sheet held on with a horrible sticky goo. Peel this back, and be careful not to get the goo on your clothing. You should then have access to the inside of the door - at this point you might be able to see the problem. If not, find the wiring to the central locking actuator and disconnect it - this should stop it from interfering with the system, so you can still lock all the other doors automatically. You can then investigate further to figure out the underlying problem...